# How to covert currency as per locale ID

Tags: asp-classic, currency, lcid

I am using locale Id(LCID) in classic ASP. 
I have currency in 7177 locale Id(South Africa).
I want to convert it to the currency with locale id 3081(Australia).
For example, if input is 13,10 then output should be 13.10.

I try this :

```
function getNumberStr(number)
    response.write("session.lcid" & session.lcid &"number:" & number & "</br>") 
    currentLCID = session.lcid

    session.lcid = 3081
    number = formatcurrency(number)
    str = Cstr(number)
    response.write("session.lcid" & session.lcid &"number:" & number & "str:" & str & "</br>") 
    session.lcid = currentLCID
    getNumberStr = str
end function
```

My initial locale Id is 7177 and I am calling this function like:

```
x = "10,10"
getNumberStr(x)
```

but i am not getting expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the expression to be formatted as a number:

```
x = CDbl("10,10")
getNumberStr(x)
```